# How does this Fibonacci function work?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fibonacci

Can anybody tell me how the following function works?

Especially the `fibu'`-thing and the tuples? Thanks!

```
fibu :: Integer -> Integer
fibu x = fst (fibu' x)
      where fibu' 0 = (0, 0)
            fibu' 1 = (1, 0)
            fibu' n = (a + l, l)
                      where (l, a) = fibu' (n-1)
```

Comment: What parts have you difficulties with?

Comment: as i  mentioned before with fibu', the tupels and the second where

Comment: isn't the last `fibu'` clause `fibu' n = (a + l, l)` (with `+ l` instead of `+ 1`).

Comment: oh, my mistake. yup, its a 'L'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first analyze

```
fibu' 0 = (0, 0)
fibu' 1 = (1, 0)
fibu' n = (a + l, l)
    where (l, a) = fibu' (n-1)
```

Here we have a function that takes as input a number *i*, and returns a 2-tuple with two numbers. The two numbers are *(F<sub>i</sub>, F<sub>i-1</sub>)* with *F<sub>i</sub>* the *i*-th Fibonacci number.

The first two numbers (for *i = 0*, and *i = 1*) are hardcoded (as `(0, 0)` and `(1, 0)`). But of course we can not keep hardcoding Fibonacci values. In case *i* is not `0` or `1`, the last line will be fired. This case is implemented to handle the `i-1` case.

In that case we recursively calculate `fibu' (n-1)` (so the tuple that contains *(F<sub>n-1</sub>, F<sub>n-2</sub>)*, we calculate this in the two previous Fibonacci numbers. We then know that (this is the Fibonacci inductive relation *F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n-1</sub> + F<sub>n-2</sub>*). So that means that we can return `(a+l, l)`. So if we call for instance `fibu' 5`, it will call `fibu' 4`, `fibu' 3`, etc. until we reach `fibu' 1` and then we will each time construct a new tuple that will keep calculating the last two Fibonacci numbers, until we have reached the Fibonacci numbers with index `5`.

Now the only problem with `fibu'` is that it returns a 2-tuple, and a user usually wants to get a simple number (the *i*-th Fibonacci number). So now we define a function:

```
fibu :: Integer -Integer
fibu x = fst (fibu' x)
```

This will return the *first* item of the 2-tuple (which is the *i*-th Fibonacci number).

Answer (score 4):

You may have seen the naïve implementation of the Fibonacci sequence:

```
fibo :: Integer -> Integer
fibo 0 = 0
fibo 1 = 1
fibo n = fibo (n-1) + fibo (n-2)
```

Well, the problem with this is that the function calls itself *twice*, recursively. And each of these calls calls itself twice again... so you end up with exponentially many calls.

What the implementation you're asking about does to solve this problem: it returns not only the *n*-th Fibonacci number, but both the *n*-th and *n*−1-th. Then the *n*+1-call only needs *one* extra invocation, not two, because that one invocation gives it all that's needed to calculate the next element of the sequence.

For the final result, you don't want two numbers but only one though, therefore the penultimate value is discarded using `fst`.